# Создание бинарного дерева, содержащего данные разных типов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, дерево, бинарное-дерево, динамические-структуры

У меня есть следующая структура:

```
template <typename T>
struct Attribute
{
    Attribute() {
        name = "EmptyAtribute";
        value = NULL;
    }
    Attribute(string name,T value) {
        this->name = name;
        this->value = value;
    }
    string name;
    T value;
};
```

Подобие самой обыкновенной пары. Получается, каждый атрибут имеет поле `name` (которое у всех строка) и шаблонное `value`.
Теперь мне необходимо создать какую-либо динамическую структуру данных, которая эти атрибуты будет хранить - `class AttributeList`.
Идея была использовать бинарное дерево, где поле `name` будет ключом, а `value` - значением. (Я посчитал, что дерево использовать лучше, так как я часто буду обращаться к атрибутам именно по их ключу - полю `name`).
Получается, узел дерева содержит в себе два указателя (`pLeft`, `pRight`) и, непосредственно, объект структуры `Attribute`, но так как структура `Attribute` шаблонная, то и узел, а значит и само дерево должны быть шаблонными.
Прошу, пожалуйста, помочь мне создать дерево, где я смогу хранить Атрибуты с разными типами поля `value`. Чтобы тип `value` я мог указывать при добавлении нового узла.

P.S. Я сделал метод `add` вместо всего класса `AttributeList` шаблонным, но у меня возникли проблемы с созданием root-узла. Я хочу иметь возможность создать объект класса `AttributeList` в тот момент, пока я ещё не знаю, чем буду его заполнять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# include <string>
using std::string;

// этот класс не шаблон
// но потомки будут шаблонами
struct AttributeBase {
  string name;
  AttributeBase(string const & n);
  // деструктор обязательно виртуальный
  virtual ~ AttributeBase(){}
};

AttributeBase::AttributeBase(string const & n):
 name{n}{}

struct BTree{
  BTree * pLeft { } ;
  BTree * pRight { } ;
  // из-за неопределённого размера
  // атрибуты могут быть только указателями
  // тип указателя не шаблон,
  // но на виртуальные шаблонные типы
  AttributeBase * attr { } ;
  BTree();
  // для удаления атрибутов нужен деструктор
  ~ BTree();
  void ChangeAttr(AttributeBase * at);
};

BTree::BTree(){}

BTree::~ BTree(){
  // атрибут удаляется виртуально
  delete attr;
}

void  BTree::ChangeAttr(AttributeBase * at){
  // атрибут удаляется виртуально
  delete attr;
  attr = at;
}

template <typename T>
struct Attribute : public AttributeBase
{
    // аргументы передавать по значению это плохая практика
    Attribute(string const & name,T const & value );
    T value ;
    virtual ~ Attribute();
};

template <typename T>
Attribute<T>::Attribute(string const & n,T const & v) :
  AttributeBase{n},value{v}{
  }

template <typename T>
Attribute<T> :: ~ Attribute(){}

struct XY{
  int c[2];
} ;

int main(){
  BTree bt ;
  // в bt пустой артибут с указателем NULL
  BTree btle ;
  // атрибуты могут быть удалены, по-этому 
  // должны находиться в свободной памяти
  Attribute<int> * ai = new Attribute<int>{"IntAttr",1};
  btle.ChangeAttr(ai);
  BTree btri ;
  Attribute<string> * as = new Attribute<string>{"StrAttr","string"};
  btri.ChangeAttr(as);
  Attribute<XY> * ai2 = 
    new Attribute<XY>{"KoordAttr",{3,4}};
  // удаляется старый атрибут, даём указатель на новый
  btri.ChangeAttr(ai2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите хранить разные типы значений *одновременно*? тогда я вижу два варианта...

1. Решение из С - `void*` плюс поле, указывающее тип того, на что указывает указатель (и только указатель - потому что разные типы могут иметь разные размеры, например...)
2. Использовать для значения обертку - класс [`any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).